# How to align bottom navigation bar icon center without text?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-bottomnav

In my app, using bottom navigation bar. Inside bottom navigation bar,text not needed. so i put `android:title=""` but that icon always in top. how to set center?
 [image: This is Mine]
[image: I need this type]

Comment: try  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44342585/8089770)

Comment: if you done this issues, please help me out from this.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you [BottomNavigationViewHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47547040/5468224)

Comment: If you have solved could you please post the solution as i am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `app:labelVisibilityMode` attribute to BottomNavigationView like below. Then it automatically center positions the icons.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
...
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
/>
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/LabelVisibilityMode